# XSD with required elements and unknown elements

Tags: xsd

I have the following xml:

```
<product>
<name>beef</name>
<category>food</category>
<unknownfield1>..</unknownfield1>
<unknownfield2>..</unknownfield2>
</product>
```

I need to validate this xml to ensure the root element is product and it contains the required elements name and category. The catch is that its not allways structered like the above example. It might be like this.

```
<product>
<category>food</category>
<unknownfield4>..</unknownfield4>
<name>beef</name>
<unknownfield4>..</unknownfield4>
</product>
```

If the structure didnt change, i could use the following:

```
<xs:element name="product">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" />
<xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"></xs:any>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but that obviously doesnt work when the element sequence is unknown.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example schema that will validate against both of the example XML files you provided:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="unknownfield4"/>
<xs:element name="unknownfield2"/>
<xs:element name="unknownfield1"/>
<xs:element name="product">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="name"/>
                <xs:element ref="category"/>
                <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="category"/>
                <xs:any/>
                <xs:element ref="name"/>
                <xs:any/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="name">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="category">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: but the all element doesnt accept the any element which is needed because of the unknown elements.

Comment: It's messy, but you could add `<xs:any>` elements in between each known element.

Comment: I dont think that would work either. Sometimes the the name element comes before the category element and sometimes the other way around. Can you give an example that works with the 2 xml examples in the question?

Comment: I updated my answer above with an example schema that validates against both of your examples. I hope that this helps!

Comment: Got to give you credit for your answer. Its not pretty, but it does the job. I actually thought it could be solved more elegant/generic, because all i wanted to do was to check for some unordered required fields. But thanks anyway! :)